# Next.js - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, typeerror

Since refactoring my code to move generic hooks and components to their own git submodules within my project I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')` whenever I call one of my custom hooks referring to `useMemo`.

I removed all the logic from a hook to make sure it didn't come from undefined arguments, so now my file looks like:

```
import { useMemo } from 'react'

export function useMyCustomHook() {
    return useMemo(() => [], []) // Does nothing useful, but fails anyway
}

export function useMyCustomHookWithoutMemo() {
    return [] // Does nothing useful, doesn't fail
}
```

I'm using next.js at the lastest version and
the project structure is like this:

- components/

  - component.js (this is where I call `useMyCustomHook` imported from 'generics')
- hooks/
- pages/

  - index.js (returns component)
- generics/

  - index.js (with `export * from './hooks/useMyCustomHook'`)
  - hooks/

    - useMyCustomHook.js

I also have a jsconfig.json file with the following content, so I can write stuff like `import Component from 'components/component'`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "."
  }
}
```

Is next.js not compiling code in my generics folder? How can I get `useMemo` to work with this folder structure?

I tried moving useMyCustomHook.js to the hooks folder and it works there, so I'm guessing it has to do with a webpack config? I don't know much about those, that's why I love next.js

Comment: @Hugo I think it's not related to useMemo :/ Maybe somewhere in your code you are trying to get properties of null object. Is it possible to you to share a bit more about the custom hook?

Comment: @AdelArmand I thought the same thing, that's why I removed all the logic from both the hook and my component and I still get the `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')` as soon as I use `useMemo`. I can add the practically empty component calling `myCustomHook` and returning an empty `div` to the question if you think that'd help, or did you have something else in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started from scratch and moved files one by one into a `libs` folder, and added `paths` in `jsconfig.json` so I wouldn't have long imports into my libs and it seems to work for now. Probably a bug with next.js, webpack and git submodules

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can add a console line after import line to ensure if useMemo exist. like this:

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
console.log(useMemo);
```

the point is to find the variable whose value is null.

Comment: useMemo is null

Answer (score 1):

This might be a case of circular imports in your code. Webpack doesn't handle them well.

Make sure that you're not importing from `components` folder to generics or hooks. Try to run `no-cycle` eslint rule on your app, it might help to identify those: https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-cycle.md

Answer (score 1):

useMemo() is available for react 16.8.6+, So if your react is not updated, you should update it, otherwise, i would try something like:

```
useMemo(()=>console.log("test),[])
```

and check dev tab in browser.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that had placed the useMemo out of the function component by mistake

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue of React being null in Next.js 13. I resolved it by adding

```
experimental: { appDir: false }
```

to my `next.config.js`.

Note: This would only apply if you are still using the `pages` directory and not the `app` directory.